# Latex IEEE bibliography style used for final publication

Tags: ieee, bibtex

IEEE provides `IEEEtran.bst`, however this one is rather not used by the IEEE when the article is finally published. Why do I think so? Well, if you look inside the  `IEEEtran.bst` you will notice that it does not handle for example `urldate` or `doi` attributes. However, both `urldate` and `doi` are nicely formatted in the references in the final publication. I doubt they format it manually as it would be a waste of time.

Does anyone know what style is used by the IEEE in final publication and whether it is officially available for download?

Comment: Why don't you just provide your .bib and use ieeetr style in your LaTeX source, and leave the rest to the IEEE production crew.